# What is LaTeX's \if@nobreak mechanism for and how does it work?

Tags: macros, latex-base

many LaTeX sectioning-related commands have a block in manipulating the `\@nobreak` flag. Taking the following example for the sake of example:

```
\begingroup
\parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth 
\parfillskip -\@pnumwidth 
{\leavevmode 
\large \bfseries #1 
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern 1.5mu\cdot\mkern 1.5mu$} 
\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par 
\nobreak 
\global\@nobreaktrue 
\everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}% 
\endgroup 
\fi}
```

(from an implementation of `\l@chapter`), I am looking to understand why the mechanism is required and how it works in detail.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @egreg In what circumstance does it work, could you provide a case and explain it, thank you!

Comment: @egreg I've edited to try to make into a question: as I understand it the idea is to explain why this is needed and how it works, in particular the reset bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\nobreak` macro prevents a break after the current material. That's standard for headings amongst other places: no line break should come between the heading and the following text. In LaTeX, a common construct is

```
\section{Some section}
\label{sec:important}

Text here
```

Using just a `\nobreak` inside `\section`, the break would keep the label with the section heading but then the text could split off. To prevent this, LaTeX sets the `\@nobreak` flag inside the section code. This is picked up by `\label` (or rather by an internal command, `\protected@write`) and a second `\nobreak` is inserted. The result is that the block of section, label and text cannot have a page break inserted.

To turn the flag off, the `\everypar` hook is used. This is inserted by TeX when it starts a paragraph, so for example when TeX finds the `T` in `Text here` in my example. At this stage, the `\nobreak` is safely inserted so the flag is switched off so that the next `\label` or whatever doesn't add one that's not needed. Everything is done globally for this mechanism as the hook can be inside a group. A trivial example

```
\section{Some section}
\label{sec:important}

{\texttt Text here}
```

which would mean that a local flag could get 'stuck on'. The construct

```
\everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}
```

means that not only is the flag cleared but also the reset itself is removed from further action.

---

All of the above applies most obviously to section headings, but the same mechanism is used in a few places (search `latex.ltx` for `@nobreak` to see them all). In the example in the question we are looking at parts as displayed in the table of contents. When a part is inserted, no break is allowed before the following chapter/section/whatever, while breaks are allowed between chapters/sections. To see why the `\@nobreak` flag has to be set, look at the standard definition of `\l@chapter`:

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

The first thing this does is use `\addpenalty`, which without the `\@nobreak` flag would undo the work of the `\nobreak` inserted by `\l@part`. (You can readily test this by redefining `\l@part` with a suitably set-up demo file.) However, `\addpenalty` checks the `\@nobreak` flag as part of its work: with the flag on, no additional penalty is added and so a page break is still prevented after the line for a chapter.

---

A note on `\protected@write`. It reads

```
\begingroup 
  \let \thepage \relax
  #2%
  \let \protect \@unexpandable@protect
  \edef \reserved@a {\write #1{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
\endgroup
\if@nobreak
  \ifvmode
    \nobreak
  \fi
\fi
```

and thus tests for the no break flag. If TeX is in vertical mode, as it is after a `\section` (which ends in a `\par` token) then a break is prevented: this is what keeps the following text with the label, which is itself kept with the section heading.

Comment: To put it in simple sentenes. the first \nobreak prohibits page splitting before the part and the first chapter(in context or our question); \global\@nobreaktrue works with the command \nobreak to achieve this function, therefore the flage \@nobreak must be needed and be set true.  \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}% breaks are allowed for the following Chapter/Section/Subsection....etc.

Comment: @JosephWright Could you explain "picked up by `\protected@write`". I do not see how a `\nobreak` is inserted after `\label`, for example, by `\section` code.

Comment: I think I understand it now! So `\everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}` is used when breaking is permitted after a sectioning command/label. What confuses me is that I would expect `\everypar{\global\@nobreaktrue\everypar{}}` or just `\@nobreaktrue` somewhere in `\@startsection` such that it gets passed to the `\label` (`\protected@write`'s `\if@nobreak`) but I cannot find it...