# Chapter content disappears beyond page-layout

Tags: page-breaking, chapters

For some reason my "Languages" chapter is not appearing properly: it's as if parts of it were not respecting my page layout (see A on the screen-capture).

Also, and it's probably related, there's now a blank page right after "Chapter 1" when "chapter 2" should instead appear there  (see B on the screen-capture).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

[image]

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered]{book}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

% Creating Index
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
%\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
%\makeindex[columns=3,title=Index,intoc,options={-s indexstyle.ist}]
%\usepackage{showidx} %To print all index entries in right margin to proofread entries

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

% Styling Chapter appearance
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}
{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%%%%%TEST_ZONE%%%%%%

\newglossaryentry{naiive}
{
    name=na\"{\i}ve,
    description={is a French loanword (adjective, form of naïf)
        indicating having or showing a lack of experience,
        understanding or sophistication}
}

%%%%%TEST_ZONE%%%%%%

%Table of Content depth
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

%Hyperlinks for TOC
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}

    %\layout    

    % FRONTMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \frontmatter

    \title{The Book of Wonders}
    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage

    \listoftables
    \clearpage

    \thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
    \section*{Preface}
    \blindtext
    \clearpage

    \thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
    \section*{Introduction}
    \blindtext
    \clearpage

    % MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \mainmatter

    \chapter{The Story}

    \section{Data}

    \index{Plants}
    \index{star}
    \index{Mu}
    \index{Sinis}
    \index{Ball}

    \chapter{Languages}

    \section{Pronunciation}

    \section{Scripts}

    \subsection{Tina}

    \subsubsection{Consonants}

    \subsubsection{Vowels}

    \subsubsection{Numerals}

    \subsubsection{Special Symbols}

    \subsection{Anna}

    \subsubsection{Consonants}

    \subsubsection{Vowel Diacritics}

    \subsubsection{Diphthongal Diacritics}

    \subsubsection{Numerals}

    \subsubsection{Special Symbols}

    \subsubsection{Common Determinatives}

    \subsection{Herbert}

    \subsubsection{Consonants}

    \subsubsection{Vowel Diacritics}

    \subsubsection{Consonants}

    \subsubsection{Vowels}

    \subsubsection{Numerals}

    \subsubsection{Special Symbols}

    \subsection{Jennifer}

    \subsubsection{Consonants}

    \subsubsection{Vowel Diacritics}

    \subsubsection{Special Symbols}

    \subsection{Mike}

    \subsubsection{Consonants}

    \subsubsection{Vowel Diacritics}

    \subsubsection{Special Symbols}

    \subsection{Script Samples}

    \backmatter

    \printglossaries
    \printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, please note for your next question that this is not an MWE, you can remove lots of lines in the preamble.
Second, your problem will solve itself once you add some text in any of the section/subsections. For some reason LaTeX does not allow any pagebreaks for consecutive `\section`/`\subsection` commands. I tried to find a solution for that, but failed so far.

Comment: @Timm the lack of page breaks is by design

Comment: latex does not allow a page break after a section heading, you never want a heading at the bottom of a page.  while drafting just add  `abc` or `\mbox{]` or any other visible or invisible text after each heading. (I am sure this is a duplicate, will find an older question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, good to know. I figured it wouldn't allow a page break *after* a section, but would *before*. Ended up in my head to be a `0/0` equation and then I just passed out ;).

Comment: @Timm I can't see a duplicate do you want to answer?

Comment: @David, thanks for giving me a try. I answered and tried to make it as complete as possible.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Overfull box and broken pagination with page that contains only section headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57857)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll give it a try:

All sectioning commands do not allow a page break right after them to prevent them from standing alone. Once you add text to the corresponding section, a page break will automatically be **after** the text.

So, adding arbitrary text, or and an \mbox{} as [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) suggested would solve your problem.

---

For the background I did some research myself, and will do my best to explain based on the `\section` command:

The `\section` command for the [`book` class](https://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf) is defined as

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

Therein the `\@startsection` command is actually a low level TeX command:

```
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
```

Here we have a `\if@nobreak  \everypar{}`, which delays a `\nobreak` command until text has been added, to prevent this text from being separated from the sectioning command ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198175/100384)). Once (La)TeX comes upon the text, the `\nobreak` is inserted.

Now, to my believe, the original `\nobreak` is inserted by an `\@xsect` command, defined in [latex.ltx](http://ftp.itam.mx/pub/academico/investig/latex/LaTeXWin/base/latex.ltx)

```
\def\@xsect#1{%
  \@tempskipa #1\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \par \nobreak
    \vskip \@tempskipa
    \@afterheading
  \else
    \@nobreakfalse
    \global\@noskipsectrue
    \everypar{%
      \if@noskipsec
        \global\@noskipsecfalse
       {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
        \clubpenalty\@M
        \begingroup \@svsechd \endgroup
        \unskip
        \@tempskipa #1\relax
        \hskip -\@tempskipa
      \else
        \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
        \everypar{}%
      \fi}%
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}
```

which again is called by the `\@sect` macro used in ever `@startsection`

```
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
```