# Wrong layout with titlesec: it won't change page after new section

Tags: titlesec

I tried the following layout

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\vspace{1cm}\titlerule\vspace{.8ex}%
   \bfseries\large}
  {\Roman{section}\,|}
  {.5em}
  {#1}

\titlespacing{\section}{0.5ex}{*1}{*0}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

But all the titles are put on the page 2, with a strong vertical overfull box: see the image below.

[image]

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Put some text in between (not just a blank line).

Comment: I would like (if possible) to possibly not put any text after a `\section{}`. But, indeed, it works with `\mbox{}` although it adds some vertical space.

Comment: Well, it is intended behavior that two sections following each other do not break (if I recall correctly).

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57861/164314) is probably what @TeXnician is referring to. If you want more details, have a look at [this more recent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357732/164314).